# Input shape axis 0 must equal 4, got shape [5] when trying to crop image batch in tensorflow dataset pipeline

Tags: tensorflow, tf.data.dataset, tf.dataset

I get the following error when I try to crop a batch of images inside a `tf.data.Dataset` pipeline:

> InvalidArgumentError: Input shape axis 0 must equal 4, got shape [5]
> [[{{node crop_to_bounding_box/unstack}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

```
def crop(img_batch, label_batch):
    #cropped_image = img_batch
    cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(img_batch, 0, 0, 100, 100)
    return cropped_image, label_batch


train_dataset_cropped = train_dataset.map(crop)
```

But when I try to run the following for loop I get the mentioned error:

```
for img_batch, label_batch in train_dataset_cropped:
    print(type(img_batch), img_batch.shape, label_batch.shape)
```

Note that the pipeline works without the `tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box` inside the `crop` function (directly using `cropped_image = img_batch`).

Do you know how to correctly crop a batch of images inside a tf.data.Dataset pipeline?

Comment: I have a similar error. I'll give you my solution if I find one

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any documentation for this, but I think you can't call methods from `tf.image` in a method that will be used within a `tf.data.Dataset.map`. A simple workaround for your problem is then to do:

```py
def crop(img_batch, label_batch):
    cropped_image = img_batch[:, :100, :100] # if your dataset is already batched
    # cropped_image = img_batch[:100, :100] # otherwise
    return cropped_image, label_batch
```